# Source control system to branch by user instead of version

Tags: version-control

Once again, I'm a bit stumped about the best stack-exchange site on which to post this question. But I think developers are best suited to answer questions about source control, so here it is.

I am considering a crowd-sourced, user-rated game development project and am wondering what, if any, source control and merging systems might best be capable of hosting the kinds of source control I'm interested in. By user-rated, I mean that there will be some kind of rating/voting system like that found here on StackOverflow. For some details on the project idea, you can read my posting about it at http://gamedev.enigmadream.com/index.php?topic=1589.0. What I think I need is:

1. Ability to branch by user and maximize merging capabilities. I know source control systems are mainly focused on branching by version, and we could maybe think of each user maintaining their own version. But I guess we need some really robust merging capabilities to maximize the abilities of one user to merge changes from another user into their own branch, for example. So I think I would like the ability for "cross-branch" merging without having to merge into the common root branch first. (I'm most familiar with Team Foundation Server (TFS), which doesn't easily support this.)
2. Massive branching and merging. If there are hundreds or thousands of people wanting to incorporate their own changes into the project, there could be a lot of branches, and the system would need to be able to handle that without a meltdown. A single user might want to create multiple branches deriving from multiple other users' branches under their own name too, ideally, with the ability to merge among them to some extent.
3. Permission control by branch. I see SourceForge supports Subversion and Mercurial, but does not currently support permission controls by path/branch on these (as far as I can tell), although that does appear to be a feature under consideration. Users should be limited from pushing their code into other branches. I suspect the normal operations for a user would be pulling edits from other branches into their own branch, and checking in additional changes in their own branch.
4. A voting system. I know I shouldn't expect a source control system to support voting natively, but anything that could contribute to making this possible would be helpful. For example, maybe a voting system would involve or rely on the ability to label the best edits from various branches and pull them into a single file based on a label or a set of labels.  And anything that would assist in merging the results of a selected set of labels from various branches (perhaps applying a new label to the set) could help too.
5. Very few files and possibly no directories. I would be willing to give up the ability to manage a large number of files or directories in exchange to gain any of the above because the format for the game file I'm considering is generally contained in a single text (XML or HTML5 -- haven't decided yet) file.  But this does mean that the system should be pretty good at merging edits to relatively large text files efficiently.  I know Team Foundation Server does a pretty good job of maintaining just changes to a file. I hope other source control systems do at least as well.

Or is source control not the proper paradigm to be talking about here? Is there some other technology ideal for merging code like this, one that doesn't involve source control and/or branching the way I'm thinking about it?

Comment: @martin-geisler I think, *VCS-specific* tags also not-applicable here, for **so wide and common** question

Comment: @LazyBadger: yeah, I think you're right — this is not really about any particular version control system.

Comment: @MartinGeisler I included specific tags because I thought the experts in those systems would be able to respond with info about how well those individual systems applied to this use case.

Comment: @BlueMonkMN: okay, but I think those experts should subscribe to the version-control tag if they are interested in questions like this that are only related to version control. You can add the tags back if you don't agree with this, however.

Comment: @MartinGeisler I will leave it as-is. If I ask a similar question in the future, I will be sure to explicitly call out each specific technology I want to know about in the question and not just in the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **Any VCS**, because "...source control systems are mainly focused on branching by version..." is **just wrong**, VCS support *diverged changes of code over time*, nothing more and nothing less
2. **Any DVCS**, because they have reasonable good branch-merge capabilities from the ground
3. **Mercurial**, which have branch-level ACLs, **SVN** have path-based ACLs. And because Subversion have *physical tree repository* (at some degree), ACLs can be applied to any part of subtree, i.e to branches also
4. **Any CodeReview** tool, integrated with VCS and modified for specific-reqs
5. **Fossil SCM** is single-file portable EXE, repo - one file; **any DVCS** also add only one dir of repo to existing tree and handle big files without headache

Comment: 2: TFS is a DVCS, right? It seems to only have good support for merging into parents and descendants, not siblings, so I would like a little more specific answer here. Is TFS the only DVCS that does not support cross-branch merging (of siblings)? 3: You say that SVN supports path-based ACLs. Are you implying that it does not support branch based ACLs? If that's the case, I would want to avoid SVN assuming I want each user to have their own branch, right? 4: Are there significant differences in labeling features to be aware of? 5: Does Fossil SCM work for #3 (supporting permission control)?

Comment: Also, how well does git and github fulfill these requirements? Since you didn't mention git in any of your response, should I conclude that it's not suitable for #3?

Comment: @BlueMonkMN - I know about TFS almost nothing, but "Team Foundation Server is the Lotus Notes of version control tools"(http://jamesmckay.net/2011/02/team-foundation-server-is-the-lotus-notes-of-version-control-tools/) and only *fact of baseless-merge in TFS kills me* 3. I edited my answer for SVN path-bsed ACLs, but, anyway, I'll recommend to see at SVN with caution for your use-case (due to CVCS nature and centralized management) 4. Not sure, I have minimal experience with CR-tools 5. http://www.mail-archive.com/fossil-users@lists.fossil-scm.org/msg03822.html answered "No"

Comment: @BlueMonkMN - "any DVCS" is git-inclusive by definition. I dislike (really - *HATE!*) git and try to avoid usage of it. Yes, AFAIK, it haven't any embedded ACLs at all (TBT), all restrictions are hook-based

Comment: It seems you can recommend Mercurial or SVN (although I don't yet understand DVCS -- I only understand CVCS -- will have to research the difference) for my case, but I wonder how many VCS are out there and if there are others I should consider. I suppose the most popular are often good choices, and Mercurial and Subversion seem to be the most popular.  Any additional advice you can offer in choosing between Mercurial vs Subversion is appreciated.

Comment: @BlueMonkMN - for this pair and you use-case - definitely Mercurial: "made by humans for humans", easy to understanding both newcomers and die-hard CVCS users, easy adopt to **any workflow**